# breadcrumb with bootstrap i want make it responsive

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

I want to make this bradcrumb responsive with the all sizes i don't know if it can but i am tried but not reach to result can you help me i am fresher on bootstrap , this is the css for the breadcrumb .

```css
/*----------------------------start-----breadcrumb----------------------------------*/

.breadcrumbb {
  /*centering*/
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  /*width: 757px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  /*Lets add the numbers for each link using CSS counters. flag is the name of the counter. to be defined using counter-reset in the parent element of the links*/
  counter-reset: flag;
}
.breadcrumbb a {
  /*width: 80px;*/
  text-align: left;
  cursor: context-menu;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: white;
  /*need more margin on the left of links to accomodate the numbers*/
  padding: 0 10px 0 60px;
  /*background: #666;*/
  /*background: linear-gradient(#b89470, #b89470);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b89470, #b89470); /* IE 11 */
  background: #dfdfdf;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #dfdfdf), color-stop(0%, #dfdfdf), color-stop(0%, #dfdfdf), color-stop(100%, #dfdfdf));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf ', endColorstr='#dfdfdf ', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
  position: relative;
}
/*since the first link does not have a triangle before it we can reduce the left padding to make it look consistent with other links*/

.breadcrumbb a:first-child {
  padding-left: 46px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  /*to match with the parent's radius*/
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.breadcrumbb a:first-child:before {
  left: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
.breadcrumbb a:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  /*this was to prevent glitches on hover*/
  padding-right: 20px;
}
/*hover/active styles*/

.breadcrumbb a.active {
  /*background: #333;*/
  /*background: linear-gradient(#5c3d1f, #5c3d1f);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5c3d1f, #5c3d1f); /* IE 11 */
  background: #6b93b7;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #6b93b7), color-stop(0%, #6b93b7), color-stop(0%, #6b93b7), color-stop(100%, #6b93b7));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6b93b7 ', endColorstr='#6b93b7 ', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
.breadcrumbb a.active:after {
  /*background: #333;*/
  /*background: linear-gradient(135deg, #5c3d1f, #5c3d1f);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5c3d1f, #5c3d1f); /* IE 11 */
  background: #6b93b7;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #6b93b7), color-stop(0%, #6b93b7), color-stop(0%, #6b93b7), color-stop(100%, #6b93b7));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6b93b7', endColorstr='#6b93b7', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
/*adding the arrows for the breadcrumbs using rotated pseudo elements*/

.breadcrumbb a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -18px;
  /*half of square's length*/
  /*same dimension as the line-height of .breadcrumb a */
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  /*as you see the rotated square takes a larger height. which makes it tough to position it properly. So we are going to scale it down so that the diagonals become equal to the line-height of the link. We scale it to 70.7% because if square's: 
 length = 1; diagonal = (1^2 + 1^2)^0.5 = 1.414 (pythagoras theorem)
 if diagonal required = 1; length = 1/1.414 = 0.707*/
  transform: scale(0.707) rotate(45deg);
  /*we need to prevent the arrows from getting buried under the next link*/
  z-index: 1;
  /*background same as links but the gradient will be rotated to compensate with the transform applied*/
  /*background: #666;*/
  /*background: linear-gradient(135deg, #b89470, #b89470);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b89470, #b89470); /* IE 11 */
  background: #dfdfdf;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #dfdfdf), color-stop(0%, #dfdfdf), color-stop(0%, #dfdfdf), color-stop(100%, #dfdfdf));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 0%, #dfdfdf 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#dfdfdf', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
  /*stylish arrow design using box shadow*/
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 3px -3px 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  /*
  5px - for rounded arrows and 
  50px - to prevent hover glitches on the border created using shadows*/
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 50px;
}
/*we dont need an arrow after the last link*/

.breadcrumbb a:last-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.notcount {
  color: #5c3d1f;
  font-size: 13px;
}
/*we will use the :before element to show numbers*/

.breadcrumbb a:before {
  content: counter(flag);
  counter-increment: flag;
  /*some styles now*/
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /*-webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;*/
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30px;
  /*background: #444;*/
  /*background: linear-gradient(#5c3d1f, #5c3d1f);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5c3d1f, #5c3d1f); /* IE 11*/
  background: #6b93b7;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #6b93b7), color-stop(0%, #6b93b7), color-stop(0%, #6b93b7), color-stop(100%, #6b93b7));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 0%, #6b93b7 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#6b93b7', endColorstr='#6b93b7', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
  font-weight: bold;
}
.flat a,
.flat a:after {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.flat a:before {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #ccc;
}
.flat a:hover,
.flat a.active,
.flat a:hover:after,
.flat a.active:after {
  background: #9EEB62;
}
/*----------------------------End-----breadcrumb----------------------------------*/
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8" style="background-color: #dfdfdf; padding: 6px 27px 20px 27px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
      <div class="breadcrumbb" style="position: relative; top: -2px;">
        <a href="#" style="" class="active">Select</a>
        <a href="#" style="">Add services</a>
        <a href="#" style="">Login</a>
        <a href="#" style="">Summary</a>
        <a href="#" style="">Confirmation</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking to achieve, do you want the breadcrumbs to collapse under each other on smaller viewports?

Comment: not collapse i make this breadcrumb to do Gide me where i am on the application i want each step on the breadcrumb take new line when i minimize the size of the screen until reach to the xs size on mobile make it one column  all step display under each other like new line for each step on the breadcrumb

Comment: @JSantosh how with media query i am not familiar with media query can you help me

Comment: the above styles will work  in all screen resolutions ,so write similar CSS inside media queries. [This](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints) will help you in all possible breakpoints in all devices. write CSS inside them.

Comment: @JSantosh thanks alot for help me

Comment: shall i post is as answer ?

Comment: @JSantosh yes this is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Media Queries and write the required CSS.

Different breakpoints are listed below ([Source](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints))

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  /* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* Large screens ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1824px) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* iPhone 4 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* iPhone 5 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* iPhone 6 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}
/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
  /* Styles */
}
```