# @media screen best practice for my dimensions

Tags: html, css

I am new to `@media` screen so please be gentile.

I do not have a fluid setup but rather a fixed setup for 3 different device setups.

```
Mobile = max-width 500px.
Tablet = max-width 740px.
Laptop/desktop/desktop hd = width 980px.
```

--

So am I correct is saying the following:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) { }
@media (max-width: 740px) { }
@media (min-width: 741px) { }
```

Comment: @PravinS thanks for the edit. I kind of rushed the question. much appreciated

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32693280/3465753) might help you

Comment: Great post @JSantosh will study and use for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the smallest screen-width last, like this:

```
@media (min-width: 741px) { }
@media (max-width: 740px) { }
@media (max-width: 500px) { }
```

As the CSS reads from the top to the bottom, then with your `max-width: 740px` will overlap, as 320px is still less than 740px.

You could also set a min-width:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) { }
@media (min-width:501px) and (max-width: 740px) { }    
@media (min-width: 741px) { }
```

Then you can place them as you want.

EDIT:

This is actually better:

```
[ CSS For 741px and above here ]

@media (max-width: 740px) { }
@media (max-width: 500px) { }
```

This way, you just need to fix widths, font-sizes and such in the media-queries, and you don't need to write background-colors and font-colors if they should stay the same.

Comment: Great thanks, one other question... if my original/default css is for screens of 741px and above... do I need to include the (-----@media (min-width: 741px) { } -----) ?

Comment: No, you can just write your css for 741px and above, and then the media-queries below that, to fix the styles. This will also do, so you don't have to set the background-color of divs in every query.

Comment: Brilliant, big help. will accept as answer once countdown timer has expired.