# How to change a div into responsive?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to this and i created a div. Can any one suggest how to change it to a responsive view.
The code is:

```
    <body>
<style>
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index : 1;
}
div img { border: 1px red solid; display: block; }
div + img { position: absolute; z-index: 100; top: 200px; right: 600px; }
</style>
<div>
 <div>
  <img src="w2.jpg" alt="" style="height: 315px; width: 851px;" />
 </div>
 <img src="w3.jpg" alt="" style="height: 160px; width: 160px;" />
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: check this link it will helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933356/change-div-order-on-responsive-design

Comment: You'll find some help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971189/constructing-a-responsive-website) about creating a responsive website

Comment: You have to write CSS in different break points. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32693280/3465753) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the updated code like the snippet at https://jsfiddle.net/c0vpp862/

```
<div>
 <div>
  <img src="http://localhost/arp/isol_cms/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/images/img/s5.png" alt="" style="height: 315px;" />
 </div>
 <img src="w3.jpghttp://localhost/arp/isol_cms/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/images/img/s5.png" alt="" style="height: 160px;" />
 </div>
```

Style

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index : 1;
}
div img { border: 1px red solid; display: block; }
div + img { position: absolute; z-index: 100; top: 200px; right: 600px; }
```

I just removed th width of both the images, if you want you can set width = 100% and remove the height of the images,

Comment: Thnx Arpita... The code was useful for me.... I make little bit of changes and used it....

Comment: @SyamSree Please accept it as an answer if this solved your problem.